# master page link generation wrong - s#arp architecture

Tags: asp.net-mvc, s#arp-architecture

I am using s#arp architecture 2.0 with asp.net mvc 3.0. The razor code in a master page looks like this:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Logout", "LogOff", "Users", new { style = "color:Blue;" })
```

For some reason the app does not produce the correct link anymore (to the action logoff of controller users) but rather points to the current controller for the action logoff. I have not changed anything. where do I have to dig to overcome this please?

The generated link looks like this:

CurrentControllerName/LogOff?Length=5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are calling a [wrong overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492124.aspx) of the ActionLink helper. Here's what you do:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "Logout",                         // linkText
    "LogOff",                         // actionName
    "Users",                          // routeValues
    new { style = "color:Blue;" }     // htmlAttributes
)
```

It's pretty obvious why this doesn't produce the correct url. You are passing `"Users"` which is a string value at the place where the helper expects `routeValues` which must represent an anonymous object.

The [correct overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972.aspx) is:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "Logout",                         // linkText
    "LogOff",                         // actionName
    "Users",                          // controllerName
    null,                             // routeValues
    new { style = "color:Blue;" }     // htmlAttributes
)
```

Comment: oh dear. for some resaon i must have deleted the null bit as it used to wrks. thanks!